# How can I install querycsv-redux for python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am unable to install **querycsv-redux** for *python*.
I don't understand the process to install the library using **pip**.
Is there any alternative to pip for installing the mentioned library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Download `tar file` from [website](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/querycsv-redux) according to version which you want to install and then extract it and run `setup.py` file present in it.

While running setup file use `python2 setup.py` if you want to install in `python2` otherwise for `python3`  use  `python3 setup.py`